# Posting data from esp8266 to a webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, esp8266

I want to send data from my esp8266 to a webapi but it fails.

I tried this code to send my data like sensor status but it fails and returns error 400. I searched a lot about this problem and I tried so many things but it didn't work.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>


const char *ssid = "VRU";  
const char *password = "";

 
const char *host = "192.168.174.71";   

WiFiClient wifiClient;

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);    
  delay(1000);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);        
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); 
  Serial.println("");

  Serial.print("Connecting");

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }


  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}


void loop() {
  HTTPClient http; 
   
  http.begin(wifiClient,"http://192.168.174.71:100/api/StatusReport/AddStatus");              
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");    

  int httpCode = http.POST("{\"status\":\"1\"}");  
  String payload = http.getString();   

  Serial.println(httpCode);   
  Serial.println(payload);    

  http.end();  
  
  delay(5000); 
}
```

Here is my code. It connects to the wifi without any problem and when it wants to post the data it returns an error.

```
400

{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-862f434a8be85865c871ea45b89544d1-cea4232cafaa5cc1-00","errors":{"status":["The status field is required."]}}
```

And it's the error.

The api receives the data when I do it by myself but the esp can't send the data.

What should I do to prevent this error from happening. Is it from the api that can't receive data or from the esp?

Comment: try `"{\"status\":1}"`

Comment: can you fit the sensor data in a GET request? those are faster and simpler than POST to construct on limited-resource machines like MCUs.